# force copy when -i is used in bash alias

Tags: unix

I have an alias (like most people do, i think) that makes `cp` `cp -i` to prevent overwriting.

Is there a way I can "cancel" this to force overwriting on a copy function? `cp -f` does not work.

Comment: Having these kind of aliases should be considered a bad habit; it will teach you to be sloppy with your commands, and then one day you'll be on another machine without these aliases (or even just a freshly-installed OS where you haven't imported your .bashrc yet) and you'll make a mistake. You'll also get into the habit of just automatically pressing 'y' so it won't offer much real protection. If you really want this kind of alias (and I think it is a pointless one, but to each their own), at least name it something other than the builtin command (call it 'mycp' or something).

Comment: Yes, having `cp` an alias for `cp -i` is bad, bad, bad! Please don't do it. However having an alias for `cp -i` is perfectly fine (I've used `copy` for years) - just don't call it `cp`.

Comment: good idea @hlovdal.. the alias 'came with the machine' for every server i have. I like the idea of renaming it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/1081936)):

1. the full pathname of the command: `/bin/cp -f source_file dest_file`
2. command substitution: `$(which cp) -f source_file dest_file`
3. the command builtin: `command cp -f source_file dest_file`
4. double quotation marks: `"cp" -f source_file dest_file`
5. single quotation marks: `'cp' -f source_file dest_file`
6. a backslash character: `\cp -f source_file dest_file`

Comment: just note: \cp will (in bash) only bypass the alias, NOT a function of the same name. ie :   `alias ls='echo "aliased"' ; function ls { echo "function" ; } ; ls ; \ls ; command ls` : the first (ls) will show "aliased", the 2nd (\ls) bypasses only the alias and therefore shows "function", and the 3rd (command ls) shows the output of regular ls

Comment: I'd also avoid #3, as you can `alias command=echo` or similar...

Comment: This is a nice list. You could also `unalias cp`

Answer (score 4):

The `command` builtin overrides aliases and function definitions, so `command cp -f source_file dest_file` will do the trick.

Comment: The other alternative would be to call cp explicitly, i.e. use `/bin/cp -f . . . `.  You can use `which cp` to determine the actual path to use.